# Moq ReturnsAsync returns Null when tuple<object,bool> instead of provided value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nunit, moq, .net-6.0

This is my first question so far, excuse me if it is not very well-described but I will try my best. 
I am  using Moq to mock my service layer in unit test for a post api call, and the _service.Create(...) returns a tuple value:
`Task<(Model.Receipt Receipt, bool IsIdempotent)>` 
therefor I created a tuple result and pass as ReturnsAsync like below:

```
var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Receipt>(_jsonReceiptString);
var output = (Receipt: input, IsIdempotent: true);
_service.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(input)).ReturnsAsync(output);
```

everything works fine till here, but at run time, after calling the service in the Post call, the return value is `<null,false>`!!! 
 It is sound like returning a default value instead of expected tuple. As I have logging data after this mocking, this causes a failed unit test. 
Do you have any idea if I am missing something here?

Comment: Can you post the code that is being tested by your test?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `Model.Receipt`  is a class and does not have `Equals` overloaded.

Comment: As an experiment, change `_service.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(input)).ReturnsAsync(output);` to `_service.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<Model.Receipt>)).ReturnsAsync(output);` If it works, that tells you that in the original code, your setup is expecting the method to be called with the same instance of `Model.Receipt`. You can either change your test to ensure that the same instance is passed to the method, or change your `Setup` to use `It.Is<Model.Receipt>(...function that checks to see if the argument matches some criteria...);`

Comment: @ScottHannen oh that worked! thanks... you are saying that _service.CreateAsync is expecting the input as API? because i use automapper for that ? is it the reason? this is the actuall GET method   var data = await _service.CreateAsync(_mapper.Map<Model.Receipt>(request));

Comment: It's because in the original version it's expecting the same class instance. Now you can use `It.Is` to inspect the `Receipt` passed to the function. If you update the question to show a property or a few of `Receipt` that you want to inspect then I can put the the rest in an answer. In other words, what values does `Receipt` need to have so that you'll know it's correct and the test should pass?

Answer (score 0):

This setup

```cs
_service.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(input)).ReturnsAsync(output);
```

..says that if `CreateAsync` is called and the argument is `input`, return `output`. This only works if the argument is actually the same object, the same class instance as `input`.

Sometimes that works, but often it doesn't. In this case `input` is deserialized from a string. If the code you're testing also deserializes a string you'll end up with two instances of `Receipt`. They might be identical, but they're not the same instance so the `Setup` doesn't work the way you want.

What you likely want is to set up the mock so that if you call `CreateAsync` and `input` *has certain property values* then the mock returns `output`.

I don't know what `Receipt` looks like. For the sake of demonstration let's say it looks like this

```cs
internal class Receipt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...and you want your `Setup` to return `output` if the argument passed to `CreateAsync` has the same `Id` and `Name` as `input`. In that case you could do this:

```cs
_service.Setup(x =>
        x.CreateAsync(
            It.Is<Models.Receipt>(receipt =>
                receipt.Id == input.Id
                && receipt.Name == input.Name)))
    .ReturnsAsync(output);
```

This says that `Setup` is looking for a `Receipt` argument, and when it gets that argument it's going to execute this function which returns `true` if the argument's `Id` and `Name` property match `input`'s `Id` and `Name`:

```cs
receipt =>
    receipt.Id == input.Id
    && receipt.Name == input.Name
```

---

What if you plan on writing a lot of these tests and you don't want to write that function over and over? You can also create an `IEqualityComparer` like this:

```cs
public class ReceiptEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Receipt>
{
    public bool Equals(Receipt x, Receipt y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Receipt obj)
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(obj.Id, obj.Name);
    }
}
```

Unless you need this in your production code I would define this class in the test project. This class contains the logic to compare two instances of `Receipt` and decide if they are equal.

Now your `Setup` can look like this:

```cs
_service.Setup(x =>
        x.CreateAsync(
            It.Is<Models.Receipt>(input, new ReceiptEqualityComparer())))
    .ReturnsAsync(output);
```

Now `Setup` will take the argument passed to `CreateAsync` and use `ReceiptEqualityComparer` to determine whether that argument is "equal" to `input`. If they have the same `Id` and `Name` they are equal.

---

Finally, your original code as posted in the question will work if `Receipt` implements `IEquatable<Receipt>`. That means that the class has its own built-in logic for comparing properties to see if two instances are equal. I use ReSharper to auto-generate that for me. It looks like this:

```cs
public class Receipt : IEquatable<Receipt>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Receipt? other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Id == other.Id && Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Receipt) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(Id, Name);
    }
}
```

That might make sense. But if you only need this for your test then I'd prefer either of the previous two approaches instead of modifying the production class so that the test works.